# How to change thousand separator for BarEntry when using MPAndroidChart BarChart in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create a barChart in Android using MPAndroidChart Library. As BarEntries I have values like **6500.0, 6753.0** and so on. But in the app, the values are shown like **6,500 ,  6,753** as in the image below.
Is it possible to show them as 6500, 6753?.. Thanks. I'm using Kotlin language.

[image]

Comment: I'll quote something from that actual library's readme: `Please read the documentation first, then ask all your questions on stackoverflow.com for the fastest answer.`.  Here it is in case you didn't find it: [docs](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/), [github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#documentation)

Comment: I already read the documentation but couldn't find a proper solution. I missed an aspect, the values are also formatted depending on device language, and it solved my problem